# moveit cant find GLEW -Solved. sources.list problem

Tags: ros, moveit, cmake, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Original Rosdep was done on the wrong directory by me.....sorry. This made it seem like it was a install issue, when it was not. Many thanks to **gvdhoorn**  who continues to attempt to sove these issues that are mostly due to my own inexperience.

Still working through the process.
SOLVED.

Attempting a build from source on a debian jessie installation, have rosdep all issues, yet it fails to build with an .....

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 {_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE}
Could not find GLEW (missing: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR GLEW_LIBRARY)
```

Is this an env variable that should be set? ANY pointers would be helpful , thank you.

As the ever present and helpful (gvdhoorn) requested Here is the additional data :)  :

Below is where I Rosdep'd the src dir:

```
user1@hpdeb:~/ros_catkin_ws/src$ rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install freeglut3-dev]
[sudo] password for user1: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freeglut3-dev
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install freeglut3-dev] failed
user1@hpdeb:~/ros_catkin_ws/src$
```

Here is the command I used to build the source:

```
user1@hpdeb:~/ros_catkin_ws$ catkin_make install --extend /opt/ros/indigo --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Here is where it seems to fail:

```
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'moveit_ros_perception'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit/moveit_ros/perception)
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   signals
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
  Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR GLEW_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake:35 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  moveit/moveit_ros/perception/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user1/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user1/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
user1@hpdeb:~/ros_catkin_ws$
```

Here was my attempt to install freeglut3:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'freeglut3' for regex 'freeglut3*'
freeglut3 is already the newest version.
freeglut3 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
user1@hpdeb:~/ros_catkin_ws/src$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254777/moveit-cant-find-glew--solved.-sources.list-problem/) by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2017-02-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Can you try and see whether installing [libglew-dev](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libglew-dev) helps? If it does, then perhaps the `build_depends` of one of more packages need to be updated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Could you also please include the complete error message? What you show is just a little bit of it.

Also: which specific package is complaining (that should also be shown in the full error message)?

And: is this on x86/amd64 or ARM?

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-02-16**:
Updated question with the requested error code.

Attempted to install libglew-dev... Here is the result:

```
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libglew-dev
```

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-02-16**:
Also tried this:
sudo apt-get install libglu-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libglu1-mesa-dev' instead of 'libglu-dev'
**libglu1-mesa-dev is already the newest version.**
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> user1@hpdeb:~/ros_catkin_ws/src$ rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
> ```

```
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install freeglut3-dev]
...
E: Unable to locate package freeglut3-dev
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install freeglut3-dev] failed
```

You haven't told us whether this is an ARM platform, but in any case: according to [jessie/freeglut3-dev](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/freeglut3-dev) that pkg should be available for Debian Jessie.

I'm not entirely sure whether it will solve your problem, but perhaps you can try to find out why it won't install on your platform.

Continuing with building your workspace after `rosdep` has failed doesn't make sense to me: the dependency is required, so I'm not surprised that it won't successfully build.

> ```
> freeglut3 is already the newest version.
> ```

```
freeglut3 set to manually installed.
```

The `-dev` package provides the files required, so having the regular `freeglut3` package installed is not enough.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-02-16**:
This is an xeon hp proliant server older gen. Originally I rosdeb'd the wrong directory and it came up successful. Having trouble installing freeglut3-dev. Should I be modifying the apt sources file to pull it from somewhere else?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Afaict from the page I linked to it should just be available from the regular Debian repositories. A manual invocation of `apt-get install freeglut3-dev` also fails?

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-02-16**:
my sources.list had some issues, and I was able to apt-get freeglut3-dev.  now rosdep is looking for libfcl-0.5-dev

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Are you sure you are building `indigo-devel`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
So for my own understanding: what was the problem exactly? And how did you solve it?